# Django ImageField tamplate tag not displaying

Tags: html, django, django-templates

The image is correctly saved to the static filed that I set in the setting filed. The image will display properly if I use a static path. But when I use a dynamic path, the image would not show and no error is given. As you can see the path, when called outside of  , works correctly. But when puted inside of the , both {{item.image_1.path}}, nor {{item.image_1}},would show any picture. (item is the name of the model while image_1 is the name of the image_field)

-----------For the not working dynamic path:

```
{{item.image}}
{{item.image.path}}
<img src='{{item.image}}' alt=''>
<img src='{{item.image.path}}' alt=''>

[![for the not working method[1]][1]
```

[image]

-----------For the working static path:

```
  {%  static 'arrival7.png' as pic %}
  <img src='{{pic}}' alt=''>
```

[image: for the working method]

Comment: Can you show us any errors in your console?

Comment: It says Not Found:*url site.webmanifest

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<img src="{{ item.im }}">
```